# Проблема клонирования git репозитория с виртуальной машины на локальную

Tags: git, клиент-сервер, virtualbox

Здравствуйте,
хотел дома поэкспериментировать (в учебных целях) работу с git сервером. 
Для этого создал виртуальную машину (с использованием VirtualBox) в качестве сервера. 
На виртуальной машине в качестве сетевого адаптера используется сетевой мост.
В качестве программы для осуществления работы `git` сервера использую `scm manager`.

Цель была создать удаленный репозиторий на виртуальной машине и из основного ПК передавать коммиты на сервер, т.е. на виртуальную машину.

ОС: на основном ПК стоит windows 7, 64 bit;

на ВМ (git сервере) windows 7, 32 bit.

Проблема возникла когда я пробую передавать коммиты или клонировать репозиторий из основного ПК в виртуальный у меня возникает ошибка. 
Хотя из браузера основного ПК на сервер я захожу спокойно без никаких ошибок
(по ссылке: `http://diserver:8080/scm`).

Если же (на основном ПК) в git Bash пишу  `git clone http://diserver:8080/scm/git/android5`
то возникает ошибка `fatal: repository 'http://diserver:8080/scm/git/android5/' not found`.

Если к примеру открыв git Bash на виртуальном ПК и написать

```
git clone http://localhost:8080/scm/git/android5
```

то все работает без проблем.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема ?

===================================================

Полная история ввода команды в основном ПК в git bash:

```
$ git clone http://diserver:8080/scm/git/android5

Cloning into 'android5'...

fatal: repository 'http://diserver:8080/scm/git/android5/' not found
```

Comment: Может с правами что? Для учебных целей можно и на гитхабе зарегаться

Comment: Я пробовал в scm manager галочку ставить public для репозитория, такая же ситуация. Вообще, когда захожу в scm manager через браузер основного ПК он спрашивает имя пользователя и пароль для scm manager. Когда же я набираю команду в основном ПК пока git clone 'http://diserver:8080/scm/git/android5/ никаких менюшек позволяющих вводить пароль и имя пользователя не выскакивает ну ошибка потом выскакивает как я уже писал выше.

Comment: Маленький вопрос, Вы когда делаете clone на локальной машине, в конце адреса слэш есть? А то в запросе не указан, а в он есть. Попробуйте без него.

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov, в первую строку я ввожу без слэша, а уже git bash в ответ выдает мне со слэшэм.

Comment: @Naumov зачем гитхаб? Нормальный хардкорный путь ))

Comment: Автор, если вам именно потренироваться нужно, вы вообще можете использовать  bare-репозиторий в какой-нибудь другой папке на этой же машине.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо. Этот вариант я рассматривал как крайний случай если не получиться с удаленного ПК обращаться к GIT серверу. У меня на работе по такой же схеме (правда там ПК не виртуальные а реальные) все работает без проблем, а дома почему-то возникли на пустом месте проблемы, к сожалению. Хотелось бы выяснить с чем это связано.

Comment: @foxis у вас же есть ssh-доступ на ВМ? Попробуйте по протоколу ssh клонировать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, честно говоря ssh я не рассматривал, потому что хотел сначала начать с легкого http протокола. Видимо придется попробовать с ssh, спасибо. А что вы подразумеваете под ssh доступом на ВМ ?

Comment: а если в адресе репозитория вместо имени написать айпи адрес, будет работать?

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня на виртуальной машине стоит автоматическое получение ip адреса. Через `ipconfig` узнал ip адрес ПК виртуальной машины (сервера) 192.168.1.3. Далее в основном ПК при обращении к репозиторию на ВМ вместо его имени вставил ip: `git clone http://192.168.1.3:8080/scm/git/android5`. Результат такой же: `fatal: repository 'http://192.168.1.3:8080/scm/git/android5/' not found`.

Comment: Так у Вас на виртуальной машине также винда?

Comment: @KoVadim, да кстати забыл упомянуть у меня на основном ПК windows 7 64 bit, на ВМ windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что во всем виноват фаервол windows который блокировал любые внешние связи с локального ПК через git. После полного отключения фаервола все сразу заработало.

Всем спасибо за помощь, проблема решена. :)

Comment: Наверное, хватило бы открыть нужный порт.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за подсказку, а как это сделать, где про это почитать можно ?

Comment: В настройке Windows Firewall я не разбираюсь, поищите. Порт наверняка 433й.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, хорошо, поищу, спасибо за подсказку.